# Debugging the stack corruptuion around a variable in windbg

Tags: windows, debugging, dll, windbg

i am trying to use a `.dll` in windows to test custom login in windows. This is the [source of dll](https://github.com/multiOTP/multiOTPCredentialProvider).

**Note:** *This is more of a general debugging question(& the working of .dll plugin i am using might not be required)*

The Dll loads fine ( i can visually verify this on windows logon screen) But when i enter the password & Otp and submit it gives an error saying `stack around the variable onelinew is corrupted`. as far as i can tell this means its either because of writing too much data than the buffer can hold or trying to reference something that isn't in memory?.

I tried to attach the `windbg` debugger to find the source of stack corruption & tried to look at various things like stack frames/call stacks/register values...etc .but i am stuck on how to make sense of this as i a bit new to this style of debugging(2 days now).

i will attach a screen shot of error and stack calls , hopefully someone can tell where to go on from here.

The last log in the log file created by this plugin is `MultiotpCredential::Dll compiled with SKIP_OTP_CHECK !!!!!!!!"` which is [defined here](https://github.com/multiOTP/multiOTPCredentialProvider/blob/master/MultiotpCredential.cpp)

the variable `onelinew` which is appering in error box is [defined here](https://github.com/multiOTP/multiOTPCredentialProvider/blob/master/MultiotpHelpers.cpp) as:

```
void PrintLn(const wchar_t *message, int line)
{
    INIT_ZERO_CHAR(date_time, MAX_TIME_SIZE);
    GetCurrentTimeAndDate(date_time);
    WriteLogFile(date_time);

    // MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)message, NULL, MB_ICONWARNING);

    wchar_t onelinew[1024];
    swprintf_s(onelinew, sizeof(onelinew), message, line);

    //  OutputDebugStringW(message);
    WriteLogFile(onelinew);
    WriteLogFile("\n");
}
```

[image: error image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done the more difficult part which is to find the culprit. The error message tells you that you have a stack based buffer overflow.

```c
    wchar_t onelinew[1024];
    swprintf_s(onelinew, sizeof(onelinew), message, line);
```

Note that in your case, as the code is using `wchar_t`, there are 2 bytes per character. Simply put, your buffer can contain **at most** 1024 `wchar_t`. If `message` is more than 1024 `wchar_t` (2048 **bytes**, including the null characters) then your buffer is overflowed.

The documentation for [`swprintf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=vs-2019) is not very clear, but if I'm not mistaken (I think it's clearer in the documentation for [`swprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-sprintf-l-swprintf-swprintf-l-swprintf-l?view=vs-2019)) the second parameter is the number of characters, not bytes.

The problem is that the `sizeof` operator will return the number of bytes (**2048** in this case) which tells the API that the buffer is 2048 characters but your buffer is only **1024 characters**.

Thus you should specify it like this (or use the [`_countof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/countof-macro?view=vs-2019) macro):

```
    wchar_t onelinew[1024];
    swprintf_s(onelinew, sizeof(onelinew) / sizeof(wchar_t), message, line);
```

Comment: @Neista thanks a lot, this worked!!. i was getting my head banged for last 2 days :D

Comment: And if you're working in a C++17 codebase, [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) is a good alternative to the MSVC-specific `_countof()` macro.